# How to add a dropdown menu with Logout option using ant d in React typescript

Tags: antd, react-typescript

Here is the sample code, i have a avatar and onclick of it i want to show a small dropdown with logout option and possibly username.

```
import { Avatar, Layout } from 'antd';

 <StyledAvatar size="small"> {initials} </StyledAvatar>


 const StyledAvatar = styled(Avatar)`
  margin-left: ${({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => theme.paddings.small}px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<Dropdown
  overlay={menu}
  trigger={["click"]}
  placement="bottomLeft"
>
  <div onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
    <Avatar size="large" icon={<UserOutlined />} />
  </div>
</Dropdown>
```

We put the avatar component inside the Dropdown component.